# GNU find with -exec rm removes matches, then complains they don't exist

Tags: command-line, unix, shell, find, gnu

I have a `/domains` directory in which I have entries such as

```
theawesomesite.com
0.2.v.theawesomesite.com
0.3.v.theawesomesite.com
```

And after testing 0.3, I'll set the main domain to alias the new version. Works really nice. Now, I want to be able to delete all old versions. I tried this:

```
find /domains -name "*.v.theawesomesite.com" -not -name "0.3.v.*" -ignore_readdir_race -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

The old domain directories are deleted, but for each of them `find` complains `No such file or directory`. I added the `-ignore_readdir_race` under the idea it would help, but it has not.

Any ideas how to get rid of these complaints and why `find` is complaining in the first place. It has to be `stat`ing after the `-exec` but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the `-depth` flag, to process each directory's contents prior to the directory itself.

EDIT by Asker: Or, the -prune flag, as I don't care about the contents at all. Your suggestion made me think about it searching in the directories after deleting them, which I didn't consider, and gave me the end answer, so I wanted to make this the correct answer I actually used.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `-delete` action instead of `-exec` (as long as you have recent find).

Answer (score 1):

Find is best saved for when you need to recurse directories, which it doesn't look like you do.  In this case, I would just do some shell magic.  Options include:

```
for dir in *.v.theawesomesite.com
    [[ $dir == 0.3.v.theawesomesite.com ]] || rm -r $dir
done
```

Or:

```
echo *.v.theawesomesite.com | grep -v '^0.3.v.theawesomesite.com$' | xargs rm -r
```

Or even:

```
mv 0.3.v.theawesomesite.com 0.3.v.theawesomesite.com.SAVED
rm -r *.v.theawesomesite.com
mv 0.3.v.theawesomesite.com.SAVED 0.3.v.theawesomesite.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using single-quotes instead of double-quotes.

The shell expands double-quotes before passing them to `find`, so it may be rm'ing the directory before the files:

```
find /domains -name 0.2.v.theawesomesite.com 0.2.v.theawesomesite.com/file1 ...
```

So it may process the directory first, then look for the files that it just deleted.